# How can you switch data from an activity that appears only once to another one that always appears, you register once and than you only need to login

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

HActivity.java

```
    pass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
    pass1c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
    confirm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Apref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(pref.getBoolean("act_ex", false)){
        String passs11 = pass1.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LogInAct.class);
        intent.putExtra("PASSWW", passs11);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("act_ex", true);
        ed.commit();
    }
```

// Its using java in Android Studio, it passes the password the first time you open the app but the second time you do that it will say wrong password (as I wanted) even if you type the right password (the one you registered with) how can I save it somewhere or do something with it?

LogInAct.java

```
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        edt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt3);

        Button loginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logpass = edt3.getText().toString();
                passs1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PASSW");
                passs11 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PASSWW");
            if (logpass.equals(passs1) && logpass.equals(passs11)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Photos.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                tv2.setText("wrong password");
            }


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks to me like on your "registration" screen, you're capturing the username and password, and then passing them through the intent to the Login Screen?  This works great in a single instance, but doesn't persist.

It's hard to tell just from the code, but how are you taking the user to the Login Screen on the next time they open the application?  Is it just going to that screen as the launch?

Data passed over in intents is not persisted between sessions.  It's most useful when passing data from one screen to another just for that session.

It can be used if you have a list screen and on the next screen is the detail screen.  You want to pass the id of which item they clicked for example so you can load the data on that screen.  But there is no reason to store it if they closed the app and opened it again.

To persist data between sessions, you want to store and extract from a more permanent storage.  Ideally, you'll end up with a database system of some sort.  But to answer what you're trying to do, use the shared preferences both for storing and extracting the password.

Registration:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Apref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.putString("password", password");
editor.apply();
```

Login:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Apref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
passs1 = pref.getString("username");
```

Again, this is definitely not a good way to store user's credentials, but it answers your question of persistence.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help!!
Unfortunately nothing changed, I replaced the code but now it wont enter the Log In class after the second start of the app, I want to store everything inside the app since I don't want it to use internet, I'll need to find another way I guess, but thank you kind stranger for the help, I learned something new :)

Comment: Ok yeah I think I need to see more of your logic for launching the Log in class, so I can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I deleted everything and started again with something else, right now Im posting another question since the new route I took has different problems :))